# Biometric (fingerprint/hand scan) to approve/sign a Sharepoint form or field

Tags: custom-form, mobile, digital-signature, biometric, gdpr

This is a slightly creepy subject, I know.  At work we already have a hand-scanner for clocking-in and out, so what the heck!  My question is this - is there a fingerprint app (or hand scanning app) available that could be used in a custom form in Sharepoint?  The purpose would be to sign off against a field or signing off a form.

Another of [my questions](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/238706/electronic-signature-for-forms-2013) concerned users signing off training records by signing on a tablet - their signature would be validated vs a stored signature database - some add-in software have been needed to validate whether or not the signatures matches.  But I've decided the technology seems too unreliable.

### Background

We currently use [infowise electronic signatures](https://www.infowisesolutions.com/product.aspx?id=SignatureField) for electronic signatures and the people being trained (production operatives in a factory) need input their username + password to sign a training form.  The trouble is, we don't use them very often and people forget their passwords.  It would be simpler and quicker with a fingerprint/hand scanner.

The trainee and the trainer would scan their fingerprint to 'sign off' the training as complete.  Obviously, every fingerprint is unique, so no need for usernames + passwords any more.  I would be looking to use a tablet, so sign-offs can be done on the factory floor immediately.  The tablet would be used to upload the form to Sharepoint.

Is this possible to do this in Sharepoint and using a biometric tablet?  Is there an app that can do this?

Comment: (Disclaimer) Not a promotion - You can take a look at [Docu-Sign](https://www.docusign.com/solutions/microsoft/sharepoint-2013-2016) for electronic signature

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware of any application in SharePoint that would fulfill this requirement, and there would be a lot to overcome to deliver this. I am coming from a life sciences background working with 21 CFR Part 11 / Annex 11 (ERES) compliant systems, so how I would need to approach this would vary from yours.

My assumption is that you are using this signature system to meet a compliance regulation to ensure employees have read and understood their SOPs, which is available upon request during audit to provide evidence of training. You want to remove the username/password combination and replace it with the ability to use a handprint/fingerprint to complete the authentication.

I've been looking at some ERES products and I'm not seeing many that support biometrics - DocuSign is one of the largest in the game and they do not seem to have any indication of supporting a hand/fingerprint scanner. Almost all of them use username/password combinations to complete the handshake and apply the digital signature.

Your other post indicates you are on premise, so you have a lot of options for implementing custom code to support this functionality. If you wanted to get your hands dirty you could develop this on your own utilizing a web service if your scanner has an API to leverage by capturing the result of the scan and using that to update the list item.

---

To end this with my 2 cents: Make sure you are working with your IT Compliance/QA team prior to starting on this. Introducing a change to the way a signature is captured would alter the 21 CFR Part 11 assessment for a clinical application, and we would need to re-do that assessment and determine the impact prior to accepting into production. Depending on your industry this could be a very time consuming process.

If your workers are only logging in to complete training then it may just be easier to put them in a separate OU that permits simple passwords, or permit the training facilitator to have AD access to reset passwords.

Comment: You're right on your assumptions of my requirements.  I've realised that the Infowise signature field we are using for the username+password sign-off also has a 'handwritten' signature option too.  It also gives an option for a 'Topaz Signature' too, which prompted me to check out their website.  I'm weighing up the possibility of using a Signature Pad vs a Tablet.  I had a look around for devices, there are all sorts of things.  BTW - I'm not familiar with 'ERES', but it sounds like the equivalent of GDPR legislation in the EU.

Comment: ERES is the catch all for Electronic Records / Electronic Signatures, which is just a fancy way of saying "21 CFR Part 11 Compliance" or "Annex 11" regardless of region.

I would see if just using handwritten is sufficient, or if you actually have a need for someone to enter a user/pass for authentication to approve the record.

Comment: From the research I have done so far it seems biometrics aren't really available for signing off Sharepoint forms.  I'll recommend that we use a handwritten electronic signature for form sign-off, either using a Topaz Pad (or other manufacturer) or else perhaps using a tablet + stylus pencil.  We will check if the company insurers are happy to accept an electronic signature, I don't see why they would not.  Thanks for your help.