# signature collection workflow Sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, designer-workflow

signature collection workflow share point online

is it possible to get a manual signature instead electronic signature in signature collection workflow. in this case, once the task is assigned to a person that person has to print the document and sign it manually and upload it back and from there the workflow should go to the next person for the same thing until it reaches back to the initiator of the workflow with all the manual signatures.or is there a best way to achieve this using share point designer.

How to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The obvious question is why? The user is logged on via a password and the system therefore know it is them. Electronic signature would seem as secure, is traceable and of course much more efficient.

Comment: because that is the requirement, for now i need to collect the signatures manually as I said print and sign then upload it back with out breaking the workflow, is there a way to do this if not any other best way.

Answer (score 0):

If you really must print it out for the signature (which seems a bit backwards), you can scan and email it back in to the document library.  Have a look in the document library settings/Communications/Incoming Email Settings; test adding a subject to the scan you send, you might be able to put something useful in the subject line to identify what the document is or else to categorise it in some way.

If those are your requirements, then fine.  However, I'm currently working on something similar, except I am using forms rather than documents, but I still think it is relevant.  You can use an OOTB approval/signature workflow to route documents through to the approvers (people that have to sign).  I have used an electronic signature field, Infowise can provide these (there plenty of alternatives though e.g. Adobe have something too); the signature field can be signed using a mouse (not recommended) or a signature pad (Topaz supply something which integrates well with the Infowise field).

**Further reading**

Here is a [link to a question I'd posted on signatures](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/238706/electronic-signature-for-forms-2013) - have a look at the pictures if you want an idea of how the signature strip works.

You might find browsing through the [[Digital Signature] tagged questions](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/digital-signature) useful for your research.