# Capture UserID, date/time stamp, then use it as signature in an input

Tags: list, user-profile-property, digital-signature

I used the following solution to get the userID of the current user of the SharePoint site:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20981226/sharepoint-2013-get-current-user-using-javascript

Now what I would like to do is, have some kind of way to capture this, add a time stamp and have that input into an item field of a list.  It would kind of be like the "Last Modified"/"Created by" info.

Can this be done via JavaScript only?

Comment: Which version of SharePoint you are using? I guess you have to use javascript(custom coding) only to achieve this type of requirement.

Comment: @GaneshSanap, version is 2013.  Also, I saw this done in another SharePoint site.  It was a link "Signed" when someone clicked it, it looks like a custom Modal pop up and it has their userid and I think they append a date stamp to it.  Click ok, and it updates the List, Refreshes and changes the url link property to test with the user ID and date stamp

Comment: For a digital signature you could check the Infowise site, I've posted a link to their website in one of my questions a while ago: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/238695/biometric-fingerprint-hand-scan-to-approve-sign-a-sharepoint-form-or-field  There are other companies that offer this kind of field too.  I believe Cosign is another one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be done easily in JavaScript.

If you want to get current time stamp you can use built-in `Date` object:

```
new Date()
```

In order to create new list item you can use this code as an example:

```
function createListItem(siteUrl) {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Announcements');

    var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
    this.oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
    oListItem.set_item('Title', 'My New Item!');
    oListItem.set_item('Body', 'Hello World!');
    oListItem.update();

    clientContext.load(oListItem);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), 
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
    );
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {
    alert('Item created: ' + oListItem.get_id());
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + 
        '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

On the other hand, if you already have a list item, and you want to update one of it's fields then you can use this code as an example:

```
function updateListItem(siteUrl) {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Announcements');

    this.oListItem = oList.getItemById(3);
    oListItem.set_item('Title', 'My Updated Title');
    oListItem.update();

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), 
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
    );
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {
    alert('Item updated!');
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + 
        '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Source: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-javascript-library-code-in-sharepoint#create-update-and-delete-list-items